# jQuery toggle - unexpected go top

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery, i write a simple snippetto toggle menu . But the problem is : when I scroll at the bot of page and click menu to toggle. It go top unexpectedly .

Thanks for reading .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have `<a href="#">TEXT</a>` as your link, right?

`href="#"` will make the browser scroll up to the top, so add a `return false` on click, so it looks like this:

`<a href="#" onclick="return false">TEXT</a>`; alternatively you can return `false` from your click function to prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: you know exactly what I'm doing :)
Thanks so much guy :)

Answer (score 2):

If the element is an anchor tag, capture the event object, and call the preventDefault() method; as shown below.

```
$('a#whatever').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**OR** `<a href="javascript:;" class="toggle_this" >hello world!</a>`

`e.preventDefault()` as **Matt** say is good one of course!